# PHP namespace error?

Tags: php, namespaces

PHP 5.6

This code:

```
<?php

namespace Database
{
    abstract class Model
    {

    }
}

namespace Models
{
    use Database\Model as DbModel;

    class Model extends DbModel
    {

    }
}

namespace Models
{
    use Database\Model;

    class Brand extends Model
    {

    }
}

namespace
{
    $m = new \Models\Model();
}
```

causes an error:

> "Fatal error: Cannot use Database\Model as Model because the name is already in use in D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\index.php on line 23".

This code:

```
<?php

namespace Models
{
    use Database\Model as DbModel;

    class Model extends DbModel
    {

    }
}

namespace Models
{
    use Database\Model;

    class Brand extends Model
    {

    }
}

namespace Database
{
    abstract class Model
    {

    }
}


namespace
{
    $m = new \Models\Model();
}
```

has no errors.

Why is this happening? Because the code has not been changed.

Comment: The error message should be pretty clear. You already have a `Model` class in the `Models` namespace so you cannot `use` another `Model` class. You should alias it using `use Database\Model as DatabaseModel` like in your second example.

Comment: Why in the second code, no error? Indeed, should be in the first and in the second.

Comment: Because in you second code you are aliasing the class `use Database\Model as DbModel;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After few tests:* **PHP file with few namespaces behave difficult to understand, try to do not use more then one namespace in one file.**

(It's because of linking to not existing classes while parsing [of one file!] that change order of PHP parsing, C++ things [pointers] - I can't explain that.)

As PHP doc says:
"It is strongly discouraged as a coding practice to combine multiple namespaces into the same file."

More about tests I did and documentation we studied to find it out:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71776/discussion-between-axiac-and-jack

Comment: The PHP [FAQ page about namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.conflict) warns about the conflict exposed in the question. It doesn't explain why it happens, though.

Answer (score 6):

The ordering of your namespace clauses makes the difference here; in the first example, the `Database` namespace clause is declared *before* the clause that defines the class `Models\Model`.

A similar example of that difference can be found in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.conflict):

> (...) However, the next example causes a fatal error on name conflict because MyClass is defined in the same file as the use statement.

Separate files or same file here is simulated by moving the `Database` namespace below or above, respectively.

That said, the documentation also [states](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php):

> It is strongly discouraged as a coding practice to combine multiple namespaces into the same file. The primary use case is to combine multiple PHP scripts into the same file.

#### Update

Interestingly, this problem is what Drupal 8 developers recently [found out](https://www.drupal.org/node/2446259) as well, but according to this [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62042) it has been reported more than two years ago.

A [pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1149) has been submitted to address this issue for the next major version (it may be back ported to 5.x as well).

Comment: Additional question: what `Model` class is extended by class `Brand` in the example that works? And why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71776/discussion-between-axiac-and-jack).